# JS resultset to JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following code cloned from XML output. I need the output to be a JSON object instead of an XML string but am missing something.

```
    public String evaluate() throws Exception
{
    String itemTitle = "";
    BoundStringBuilder data = new BoundStringBuilder();
    TreeMap promptValues = ReportItem.promptValuesSetStringToTreeMap(promptValuesSet);
    String debugFlag = isDebugMode ? "Y" : "N";

    // get JSON item config settings
    ExecuteProcedure ep = new ExecuteProcedure(con, "pkg_report.select_mr_JSON_config");
    ep.setParam("p_report_number", reportNumber);
    ep.setParam("p_instance_number", instanceNumber);
    ep.setParam("p_item_index", itemIndex);
    ep.setParam("p_path", null);
    ResultSet JSONConfigRs = ep.execute()[0];
    while(JSONConfigRs.next())
    {
        String setting = JSONConfigRs.getString("field_name");
        String value = UtilityMethods.nullValue(JSONConfigRs.getString("value"), "").toLowerCase();

        if(setting.equals("JSON_JSONREPORTITEM_ITEMNAME_BAN_ITEM_NAME"))
            itemTitle = value;
    }
    JSONConfigRs.close();
    ep.close();

    // execute sql
    ep = new ExecuteProcedure(con, "pkg_report.execute_mr_sql");
    ep.setParam("p_report_number", reportNumber);
    ep.setParam("p_instance_number", instanceNumber);
    ep.setParam("p_item_index", itemIndex);
    ep.setParam("p_item_type_code", itemTypeCode);
    ep.setParam("p_sub_item_index", "1");
    ep.setParam("p_sub_sub_item_index", "1");
    ep.setParam("p_prompt_values", UtilityMethods.treeMapToList(promptValues));
    ep.setParam("p_debug_flag", debugFlag);
    ResultSet rs = ep.execute()[0];

    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
    String[] columnNames = new String[rsmd.getColumnCount()];
    for(int i = 0; i < columnNames.length; i++)
        columnNames[i] = rsmd.getColumnName(i + 1).toLowerCase();

    data.append("<data name=\"").append(itemTitle).append("\">\n");

    while(rs.next())
    {
        data.append("\t<row>\n");
        for(int i = 0; i < columnNames.length; i++)
        {
            data.append("\t\t<cell name=\"").append(columnNames[i]).append("\">");
            data.append(UtilityMethods.xmlFormat(UtilityMethods.screenFormat(rs.getString(i + 1)).trim()));
            data.append("</cell>\n");
        }
        data.append("\t</row>\n");
    }
    rs.close();
    ep.close();
    data.append("</data>\n");

    String JSONData = data.toString();
    return JSONData;
}
```

I was advised "Instead of building up an XML string, you should use one the GSON JSON utility methods to dump the result set to a JSON object instead."

Can someone point me in the right direction, please. I am unfamiliar with JSON Objects, if that isn't obvious enough ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the fix that worked for me:

I removed all of the xml and table building (row/column/data) info and just dumped the result set into a GSON JSON array and output the json. Code as follows:

```
JsonArray reportArray = JsonUtilities.resultSetToJsonObjectArray(ep.execute()[0]); //Dump Result Set to JsonArray

    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
    String[] columnNames = new String[rsmd.getColumnCount()];
    for(int i = 0; i < columnNames.length; i++)
        columnNames[i] = rsmd.getColumnName(i + 1).toLowerCase();



    rs.close();
    ep.close();


    Gson gson =  new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();  //Create JSON object and format output for readability
    String JSONData = gson.toJson(reportArray);      
    return JSONData;
```

Answer (score 2):

json.org has a simple API you can use: http://json.org/java/

You could do something like this:

- iterate through your rows
- for each column, create a JSON object with name/value pairs:

column = { "column1" : 123" }

- add each column object to an array for the row

row = [ { "column1" : 123" }, { "column2" : 456" } ]

- add each row to an array

rows = [ [ { "column1" : 123" }, { "column2" : 456" } ], [ { "column1" : 111" }, { "column2" : 222" } ]]

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

JSONArray rows = new JSONArray();
while(rs.next())
    {
        JSONArray columns = new JSONArray();
        for(int i = 0; i < columnNames.length; i++)
        {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(); 
            jsonObj.put(columnNames[i], rs.getString(i + 1));
            columns.put(jsonObj);
        }
        rows.put(columns);
    }
    rs.close();
return rows.toString();
```

Comment: Fixed! I figured it out. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction kielni!